# How to remove a space in Python

Tags: python, eclipse

I need to make my sentence go on one line, but I can't figure out how. I tried the .string() but not sure if I was using it correctly. 
My code is:

```
def printCurrency(value):
    print("$" + format(value, '.2f'))

print("That is" end=" ")
printCurrency(cost)
print("for this service")
```

It is printing out like this

That is $22.00

for this service.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code for `printCurrency()` function?

Comment: Problem is in function `printCurrency(cost)`, not in this code

Comment: Rather than having a `printCurrency` function, it may be easier to have a `formatCurrency` function that returns the string `printCurrency` would have printed.

Comment: @user2357112 hm, you were 19 seconds faster than I. Why did't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I added the code for printCurrency. What do you mean by having a formatCurrency function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change `printCurrency` into `formatCurrenty` and use

```
def formatCurrency(value):
    return "$" + format(value, '.2f')  # don't print the value but return it

print("That is %s for this service" % formatCurrenty(cost))
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific issue, I would use the formatCurrency solution. If your question is more general:

To use `print` without getting a newline in Python 2.x, add a comma at the end.

e.g.

```
>>> def f():
...     print 'hello',
...     print 'world'
... 
>>> f()
hello world
```

and in Python 3.x, just set `end=''`:

```
>>> def f():
...     print('hello ', end='')
...     print('world')
... 
>>> f()
hello world
```

Comment: Note that the end applies only to the current print call.